# Is it possible for my app to delete all the device`s data (apps, pictures, etc.)?

Tags: android

I want the user to be able to delete all his data from my app.
Is it possible?

Comment: his... or her.... but anyway, is the phone asleep or off completely?

Comment: asleep.........

Comment: i ment factory reset @PKlumpp

Comment: What would that mean from a security viewpoint?

Comment: if the device you are trying to wake up doesnt have anything (like your app) then no.

Comment: @DroiDev what do you mean doesnt have anything?

Comment: so u have your phone... then you have another phone. if your phone is trying to erase another phone... if the other phone doesnt have your software on it, then no, you can not erase it.

Comment: @DroiDev you misunderstood the question look at @Eduardo Herzer answer, i only want to delete the user`s data not someone else`s data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do a factory reset programmatically, but your app must be enabled as Device Admin.

Read more here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Once your app is enabled as Device Administrator, you simple call `wipe()` from `DevicePolicyManager` (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#wipe)

Note: Your app will also be erased! It's a factory reset!

Comment: Thanks alot ill try that :) and ill accept your answer soon

Comment: Nice! It's a bit boring to implement, but it's possible... I did it already =)